# How can I fix my jQuery methods so I can re-order the items in a multiselect option control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I have an multiselect option selector and up/down buttons:

```
<select id="animalSelector" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Elephant</option>
    <option>Duck</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Giraffe</option>
    <option>Dinosaur</option>
    <option>Whale</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnMoveUp" value="^ Up" />
<input type="button" id="btnMoveDown" value="v Down" />
```

I want the user to be able to highlight/select multiple options (using the CTRL key) and then be able to move their selections up and down.

I've taken a stab at it:

```
    $('#btnMoveUp').click(function (e) {
        moveUp();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#btnMoveDown').click(function (e) {
        moveDown();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function moveUp() {
        var allOptions = $('#animalSelector').find('option');
        allOptions.filter(':selected').each(function () {
            var newPosition = allOptions.index(this) - 1;
            if (newPosition > -1) {
                allOptions.eq(newPosition).before(this);
            }
        });
    }

    function moveDown() {
        var allOptions = $('#animalSelector').find('option');
        var count = allOptions.length;
        allOptions.filter(':selected').each(function () {
            var newPosition = allOptions.index(this) + 1;
            if (newPosition < count) {
                allOptions.eq(newPosition).after(this);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, this seems to act very slow/quirky in IE7 and it has some weird behavior when the selections start to reach the top.

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way I can handle multiselect move-up/move-down behavior?

Answer (score 1):

```
function moveUp() {
    var select= $('#animalSelector')[0];
    for (var i= 1, n= select.options.length; i<n; i++)
        if (select.options[i].selected && !select.options[i-1].selected)
            select.insertBefore(select.options[i], select.options[i-1]);
}

function moveDown() {
    var select= $('#animalSelector')[0];
    for (var i= select.options.length-1; i-->0;)
        if (select.options[i].selected && !select.options[i+1].selected)
            select.insertBefore(select.options[i+1], select.options[i]);
}
```

Comment: When I run this in IE7... it takes seconds to move items up and down.  Does this not occur for you?  Is there any way I can speed it up?

Comment: you could make the select variable global, saving you the trouble of reassigning it each time, but that's not likely to gain you much. bobince's code is pretty concise.

Comment: I have a feeling it is the insertBefore() in the loop.  Modifying the dom, especially in IE7 is slow.  I'm going to somehow have to moveUp/Down the elements in memory, and then replace the entire contents of the select at once.

Comment: Seconds? How large is your options list and how many of its options are selected/moved at once? It's instantaneous for me using your example select of a few animals.